# Como desativar as sugestões do teclado virtual do Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Precisava desativar as sugestões que o teclado virtual Android busca.

Alguém tem ideia como fazer?

Uso Delphi XE7

Comment: Acredito que isso irá te ajudar:
Isso pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111350/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-in-delphi

Comment: @GustavoBitencourt isso mesmo, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @GustavoBitencourt surgiu algo novo, problema com o teclado do google, o famoso GBoard, você passou por isso?... digitar algo no EditText ele vai concatenando